# how to store url on mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

i want to know what its the correct type to store an image url on mongoDB

i try this using a type: string, but doesn`t work, when is saved on the data base does not appear nothin like a string, instead of that it shows  :  url: "false".

i need this to save the url on mongodb and upload the images on another platform.

```
Url:{
    type:String,
    default:false
},
```

after of define this on my backend, i  sent the argument whit an url on POSTMAN and this was the result on mongoDB compass.

url:"false"

Comment: Why don't you just store the string representation of the URL? I don't know what language you're using, but either cast to string or use a .toString() method.

Comment: @sleepystar96 , the language im using is javaScript in a schema for mongoDB. and mongo uses an specific typing for your data base

Answer (score 0):

1. Try matching your key you are sending from frontend "Url" or "url" and send it in string format from postman
2. This should work `Url:{ type:String, default:"" }`

Comment: from postman the url is sent but the server does not save it, it looks like url: "false",

Comment: What is the payload you're sending?

Comment: I think you need to share the code as your problem will only be solved then